# TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to build machine leaning program to compare between the images of Cat and dogs and have created TFRecords file successfully and now when i am trying to read the file for training, i am getting an error which is as given below.This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_path = 'train.tfrecords'

with tf.Session() as sess:
   feature = {'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
              'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)}
   filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path],num_epochs=1000)

   reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
   serialized_example = reader.read(queue=filename_queue,name=None)

   features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,features=feature)

   image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)

   label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)

   image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 3])

   images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1,
                                        min_after_dequeue=10)

   init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
   sess.run(init_op)

   coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

   for batch_index in range(5):
      img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
      img = img.astype(np.uint8)
      for j in range(6):
        plt.subplot(2, 3, j + 1)
        plt.imshow(img[j, ...])
        plt.title('cat' if lbl[j] == 0 else 'dog')
    pl t.show()

   coord.request_stop()

   coord.join(threads)
   sess.close()
```

I am getting this error

```
C:\Users\snklp\Anaconda3\envs\untitled\python.exe C/Users/snklp/PycharmProjects/untitled/read_tfrecords.py
2018-07-24 14:58:44.870802: I    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/snklp/PycharmProjects/untitled/read_tfrecords.py", line 18, in <module>
serialized_example = tf.TFRecordReader.read(queue=filename_queue,name=None)
TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to create a class Read with self argument in the read() function but nothing happened. I m am not getting this error. Can anybody help me in this???

Comment: The code you posted is not the code that threw the error. In the code that caused the error you are missing parentheses after `TFRecordReader` (i.e. you are not creating an actual instance of the class).

Comment: @xdurch0 the error is about line 18 of this code so how can be this possible

Comment: Line 18 in the code snippet you posted is a blank line.